# Initialize Nested Associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an associative array with the following structure

[location][product] and then [count] and [date] leaf entries

I am trying to initialize it using the code below

```
summary = {};
if(location in summary == false && product in summary == false){
        summary[location][product] = {};
}
```

then then iterating over an object of sales and assigning values using

```
summary[location][product]["count"] = count;
summary[location][product]["date"] = countDate;
```

but I am getting the error below, what am I missing

```
Type Error: summary[location] is undefined
```

Comment: Did you define summary earlier by using var summary?

Comment: @echochamber Yes I did that.

Comment: Looks like ryguy has you covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define each nested object as you go. So instead of

```
summary = {};
if(location in summary == false && product in summary == false) {
    summary[location][product] = {};
}
```

you need to type

```
summary = {}

if (!(location in summary)
    summary[location] = {}

if (!(product in summary[location]))
    summary[location][product] = {}

summary[location][product]['count'] = count
summary[location][product]['date'] = countdate
```

This will remove the error.

There may be a more efficient way of doing this that I am not aware of, but I'm sure this works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code:

```
summary = {};
if(location in summary == false && product in summary == false) {
    summary[location][product] = {};
}
```

will never set product because if location is not in summary then you wont be able to set product with:

```
summary[location][product]
```

since you can't set a product property of **null** (location)

And later when you try to access location property with:

**summary[location][product]**

the same issue happens. Location is null and you can't access its property 'product'.

P.S. if location and property is not a variable they must be in quotes like 'location' or 'product'

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you cannot assign multiple levels of undefined or null object members by name simultaneously, so something like this will fail:

```
var obj = {};
obj.member.member = someValue; // Will fail
```

*To solve this,* you could always initialize a *"skeleton"* of the object using an *object literal* before using it. That way you can avoid having to initialize the object level by level.

```
summary = {"location": {"product": {}}};
```